# sqlite3_open always returning SQLITE_OK?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

Curious about this...  it seems that even if I change the pathForResource to @"fadfdasfa" or other non-existent name, I still am logging "Database Opened"?

```
sqlite3 * myDatabase;

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"carsdatabase" ofType:@"db"];

    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &myDatabase) == SQLITE_OK)
        NSLog(@"Database Opened");
    else 
        NSLog(@"Failed to Open");
```

Comment: Well, maybe it is created if it doesn't yet exist. Did you try `sqlite3_open_v2`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The database is created for you if it does not already exist.

Comment: Note that if it does exist, as @Raloul [explains](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14295620/948581), SQLITE_OK is returned as well.

Answer (score 7):

Open the database like this:

```
std::string filename("mydatabase.db");
sqlite3 *db;
int rc = sqlite3_open_v2(filename.c_str(), &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL);
```

Then it will return an error code (14) if the database file does not exist. However, if the file exists but is not a valid database, it returns `SQLITE_OK`!

Comment: When opening in  ``SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY`` mode: one can further detect invalid files by issuing an SQL command. If this returns 26 ("file is encrypted or is not a database") then the file exists but is not an sqlite3 database file.

Answer (score 1):

This is like when you run the following in the terminal:

```
sqlite3 test.db
```

If it's not there, it would be created for you. So you just create a new database every time you change the name and probably you will see it in your main bundle.